# screen capture from window manager

Tags: x11, screen-capture, fltk

I am building a window manager in linux and wanted to add functionality to screen capture and copy to the clipboard (like "Print Screen" in Windows).  Most of the posts I came across deal with a Microsoft platform, but again, this is for linux.  What would be the most simple solution?  I am using X11 and FLTK.

I have found this exact solution - but for Windows

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1048/Screen-Capture-to-the-Clipboard

I have also found this, but it seems very overkill compared to the Windows version above

https://github.com/smasherprog/screen_capture_lite

Comment: Are you using xlib, or xcb? The xlib function is called XGetImage, I'm not sure about xcb. There are a bunch of questions about it on SO. I have no idea if fltk provides its own interface to this functionality.

Comment: @Harun I am using xlib, but will check on XGetImage.  Thanks a bunch!  Any ideas on the clipboard portion?

Comment: @user1646428 You need to acquire  - "CLIPBOARD" window selection to indicate that you have the data and later respond to selection events when client that wants to get content of event. Good description here:  https://www.uninformativ.de/blog/postings/2017-04-02/0/POSTING-en.html

Comment: @Andrey thanks!  I'll take a look at it as well :)